# `find: fts_read: Invalid argument` when working with around 8000 files

Tags: bash, find, bugs

GNU bash, version 3.2.48 has this bug; already version 3.2.57 does not.

Make a file with 8000 identical lines (say each line says `1`).  Run `split -a3 -p "1"` on it (`-p` is a BSD `split` option which makes it split on the given pattern. For a file with just one `1` per line, you can do the same thing with a standard `split` by running `split -a3 -b 1`).  And execute

```
find . -name xaaa -exec echo {} +
```

And after the expected output, you get `find: fts_read: Invalid argument` output to `cerr`.  The same error occurs when `xaaa` is replaced by any set of files, and `echo` by any other command I've tried. The length of the filename doesn't matter. The directory of the files also doesn't matter.

After some creating files elsewhere, the error is gone.  However, when `xaaa` is replaced by `xaa*` (or any other wildcard that includes multiple files, at least one of which is near the beginning of the directory listing), then the error occurs again.  At that point, no single file causes the error to appear.

Replacing `+` with `;` does avoid the error, but is not acceptable for my script.  This problem has been occurring intermittently in other situations in my script, but by reducing it I was able to come up with a simple way of replicating it.

I want the script to stop if an error occurs, but this just makes it stop very often.  Any idea how to get around this? (e.g. retrieve an error code and ignore just this specific error).

Mac OS version 10.8.5.  Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0.

Comment: Bash is not involved anywhere in the command you have shown us. `find ... -exec echo ...` is going to execute `/bin/echo` (or whichever `echo` command appears first in `$PATH`), and doesn't involve a shell at all.

Comment: As I said above, it doesn't depend on the command used.  Replacing `echo` with `cat` or `ls`, for example, still throws the same error.  And since it appears when files near the beginning of the directory listing are involved, I suspect `find` is the culprit.

Comment: I see.  I put it there in case anyone wanted to replicate it, and then complain that no error occurred on their end.  Quite plausibly, something other than the `bash` version is responsible, but I just don`t know what to check.

Comment: For that, the OS version would be useful (presumably you're on macOS?), or maybe even just `uname -r` or `uname -v`. Have you checked what the exit status of `find` is when you get this error using `$?`?

Comment: I updated the question to include the OS version and the Kernel version.  `find`'s exit status is `1`, of course, as on any other error.

Comment: `fts_read (3) - traverse a file hierarchy`: a C library function called by `find`. No external process here, no exit status. Gdb with a break on the function, and compare its args with the man page ?

Comment: I read that before asking.  But I don't know if I can `gdb` when I don't have the source code for `find`...  Unless it's available somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's very little  chance bash would be involved in there.

bash's role in that is to parse that `find . -name xaaa -exec echo {} +` code and turn that into the execution of `/path/to/find` with `find`, `.`, `-name`, `xaaa`, `-exec`, `echo`, `{}`, `+`. Any bash version would do the same.

Here, as the `find:` prefix in the error message, the error is by `find`, not `bash`, and specifically is about an error returned by the `fts_read()` function.

macos' `find` is that of FreeBSD possibly with modifications by Apple.

Thankfully, FreeBSD (if not macos) is FLOSS, and it's relatively easy to spot [where that error is output in the code there](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/1d386b48a555f61cb7325543adbbb5c3f3407a66/usr.bin/find/find.c#L237).

```c
/*
 * find_execute --
 *  take a search plan and an array of search paths and executes the plan
 *  over all FTSENT's returned for the given search paths.
 */
int
find_execute(PLAN *plan, char *paths[])
[...]
    e = errno;
    finish_execplus();
    if (e && (!ignore_readdir_race || e != ENOENT))
        errc(1, e, "fts_read");
    return (exitstatus);
}
```

At the very end of that `find_execute` function.

Here we get:

> ```
>  find: fts_read: Invalid argument
> ```

`Invalid argument` being the error message that corresponds to the `EINVAL` errno.

Here `errno` would have been set by `fts_read` as `errno` is set to 0 in the condition statement of the `while` loop just before calling `fts_read` and since we're out of the loop, that means `fts_read` just returned with `NULL`.

If you look at the [man page of `fts_read`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?fts), you'll find:

> The functions `fts_read()`   and `fts_children()` may fail and   set `errno`  for
> any  of   the  errors  specified  for  the  library  functions `chdir(2)`,
> `malloc(3)`, `opendir(3)`, `readdir(3)` and `stat(2)`.

If you follow those links to the other man pages, none of them is meant to return EINVAL.

So it very much looks like a bug either in Apple's `find` or the `fts` library there. I'd suggest you raise that to Apple support as without access to the code, there's likely little more any of us could do here.